# Enable hyperlink field in gridview while all other controls are disabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to disable all the controls on my gridview for business purposes.
`Me.gvLineItems.Enabled=False`

However, I need to enable one hyperlink field enabled so I tried this:

```
                For Each Row As GridViewRow In Me.gvLineItems.Rows
                    Dim hrf As HyperLink
                    hrf = CType(Row.Cells(16).Controls(0), HyperLink)
                    hrf.Enabled = True
                Next
```

I debug the code and it sets the hyperlink field enabled to true, but when I run the app the field is still disabled...

But If I get rid of the `Me.gvLineItems.Enabled=False` just comment that out and change my code to DISABLE the hyperlink field:

```
                For Each Row As GridViewRow In Me.gvLineItems.Rows
                    Dim hrf As HyperLink
                    hrf = CType(Row.Cells(16).Controls(0), HyperLink)
                    hrf.Enabled = False
                Next
```

This works fine...

But that is not what I need :(, just trying to reenable the link field...

### Edit

I also tried this in the rowdatabound event:

```
If Me.gvLineItems.Enabled = False Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
                    If TypeOf (e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(0)) Is HyperLink Then
                        Dim h As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(0), HyperLink)
                        h.Enabled = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
                If TypeOf (e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(0)) Is HyperLink Then
                    Dim h As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(0), HyperLink)
                    h.Enabled = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    e.Row.Cells(i).Enabled = False
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: This is *very* easy to break. My answer will work much better, once you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some type of recursive logic to loop through all the cells and disable the controls, with a condition to exclude HyperLink controls. By disabling the controls at the row level, the enabled state of the parent container (i.e. GridViewRow) will always override the enabled state of the control.

I would add some recursive logic in the `RowDataBound` event. Try something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DisableControls(e.Row);
}

private void DisableControls(WebControl parentCtrl)
{
    if (parentCtrl.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (WebControl ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = ctrl is HyperLink;
            DisableControls(ctrl);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        parentCtrl.Enabled = parentCtrl is HyperLink;
    }        
}
```

Comment: That would not work as enabled is still not a property of a `Control` type.  Please read the MSDN.

Comment: Please read the top part of my answer again. You can't disable the entire row. You have to iterate through the cells and disable the controls individually. If you disable the entire row, that will take precedence over the enabled state of any controls in the row.

Comment: I think I've replaced all instances of `Control` with `WebControl` in the `DisableControls` method, but if I missed anything, please change it to `WebControl`.